# Conditional data retention policy in Azure Data Explorer (Kusto)

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

The current Kusto data retention policy is mainly based on ingestion time. I am wondering if there is a way to define a data retention policy that is based on some other condition, or any way to mimic the behavior of a conditional data retention policy would do.

For example, I want to remove an item in the database only if there is a newer version of the same (defined by an ID column, say) item  got ingested; Otherwise, I'd want the item to be kept in the database regardless its ingestion time. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I want to remove an item in the database only if there is a newer version of the same (defined by an ID column, say) item got ingested*

You could consider creating a [materialized view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/materialized-views/materialized-view-overview) that uses `summarize arg_max(version_column, *) by id_column` - older records won't be dropped, but if you query the view instead of the table that has the raw data, they will not be visible in your queries.

Comment: Right. But since we didn't actually drop the data, the overall data size is still going to be our problem. I think Kusto only offers 4T max in terms of data capacity.

Comment: > "*I think Kusto only offers 4T max in terms of data capacity*"
the limit you mentioned is the cache size per node in some SKUs. it is not the limit on a size of a table (no such limit exists). to reduce cost, you can configure the caching policy on the raw table to be minimal, in which case - it's size on disk will be smaller

Comment: That's interesting. It might be something we were looking for. Thanks!